dask error when trying to modify categorical data
I want to transform one categorical column of my dask.DataFrame.
Precision: some categories may exist but not be present in my dataframe. It is important for me to keep them.
Here is what I am doing now:
# toy example
df = pd.DataFrame({'file': ['A.csv', 'B.csv', 'C.csv']})
df['file'] = df.file.astype('category').cat.add_categories(['D.csv'])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

# get new category
ddf["id"] = ddf["file"].cat.rename_categories(lambda x : x.split('.')[0])

When I inspect ddf["id"].cat.categories, the result is as expected:
Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object')

However, ddf.compute() raises the following error:
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

(edit) Solution:
It works using apply:
# get new category
ddf["id"] = ddf["file"].cat.rename_categories(lambda x : x.split('.')[0])


Try this code:
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame({'file': ['A.csv', 'B.csv', 'C.csv']})
df['file'] = df['file'].astype('category')
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

# Define named function for transformation
def extract_id_from_file(df):
    df['id'] = df['file'].str.split('.').str[0]
    return df

# Apply transformation using map_partitions
ddf = ddf.map_partitions(extract_id_from_file)

# Inspect new categories
print(ddf['id'].compute().unique())

# Compute dask DF
result = ddf.compute()
print(result)

Thing is, Dask cannot serialize lambda functions in distributed setup. A named function must be used instead of your lambda function.
It was also important to transform the categorical column in a way that Dask can handle, by mapping the category transformation using Dask's "map_partitions".

Thanks for your answer. Finally, this works as well:
ddf["id"] = ddf["file"].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0], meta=("id", "category"))
So I am not sure if the lambda function is really a problem. And I think using apply on one column is more efficient than map_partition on the whole dataframe.
